# Why my swift is not balanced

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I am a user of swift,but i only know a  little about it. Now i encounter a problem：in my product environment, there are ten machines as object server, 12 disk per machine, it is strange that one disk is uesed about 80%,but others only 40%.what is the reason of that ? Thanks

Comment: For future reference, the "swift" tag refers to Apple's Swift language.  You're wanting the "openstack-swift" tag I'm guessing :)

Comment: Perhaps this problem was caused by the disk,because i found the disk used about 80% was written less than the disk used 40%，further analysis   will be maked

Comment: The balancing can be a factor of the # of nodes, number of disks, and the number of replications set.   Make sure all your disks are OK, and that your nodes are all ok.  If you have a disk that is having IO issues, it will stop replicating.